# Use a string to determine table to query

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am trying to use a string to determine the table that I am performing my query on. However I can not find any way to do this. Here is my code:

```
ADVENTUREWORKSSUPEREntities context = new ADVENTUREWORKSSUPEREntities();
string table = "Addresses" //this is set elsewhere in the code but I put it here for clarity

            if (table == "Addresses")
            {
                results.ItemsSource = context.Addresses.Where(condition).ToList();
            }
            else if (table == "Customers")
            {
               results.ItemsSource = context.Customers.Where(condition).ToList();
            }
              ...
              ...
              ...
            else if (table == "SalesOrderHeaders")
            {
                results.ItemsSource = context.SalesOrderHeaders.Where(condition).ToList();
            }
```

Is it possible to replace the

```
results.ItemsSource = context.Addresses.Where(condition).ToList();
```

with a line that uses my table string instead of Addresses?
Thus it would be

```
results.ItemsSource = context.[table].Where(condition).ToList();
```

Edit:

I'm doing this as an exercise to learn wpf/entity framework/C#. As I am watching videos on puralsight I am thinking of stuff to try and adding it to this program.

Comment: using dictionary<string, string> and save condition of tables?

Comment: What do you want this for??

Comment: What is "results"? A grid, a listbox?

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat the whole point of linking your DB with entity framework? You may as well just scrap it and use ADO.NET commands at this point.

Comment: @MadHenchbot He would still be using the runtime query optimization that is going on since it still gives him the ObjectSet<TEntity>.  So, while I might not say it defeats the purpose, it definitely abstracts away some of the benefits.

Comment: @DavidReing how do you define the `(condition)` part (which is a Predicate of TEntity) if you don't have the actual entity type?

Comment: The application has a combo box that is populated at runtime with all of the table names. When a table is chosen all of the searchable fields of that table are populated in a conditions panel. The condition predicate is generated by combining the user input of those fields. Currently there are no checks to ensure valid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I came up with.

```
dynamic test = t.InvokeMember(table,
                        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, context, new object[0]);

            ((IQueryable)test).AsQueryable().Where(condition).Load();
            results.ItemsSource = test.Local;
```

Thanks to everyone that commented/answered for all the help and pointing me in good directions.

Answer (score 0):

My version (.Net 4.0) of the `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext` class contains the following public method:

`public ObjectSet<TEntity> CreateObjectSet<TEntity>(string entitySetName) where TEntity : class;`

You can use that if you wish, however, I highly doubt (and I think many people will agree with me as well) that this is a good thing to do. Please give some more background as to what you're trying to achieve, because most probably there is a much better way of doing it without having to resort to "Magic Strings".

Comment: Even with that method, you won't be able to do it since the TEntity is the dynamic type of the entity being queried, and you can't use the generic TEntity because entity framework validates that the entitySetName and the Generic match types exactly (not just base types).  See method `GetEntitySetForNameAndType`.

Comment: I'm sorry you can call it with a dynamic type, but it wouldn't be a one liner.  It would involve reflection using `Type.GetMethod` and `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type)`

Comment: @DMoses you're right, I didn't see that, but `GetEntitySetForNameAndType` does not appear in the `ObjectContext` class

Comment: @DMoses Agree, you can do it via reflection, but then again, the very fact that you have to resort to reflection hints this is not a good approach, at least not in Entity Framework

Comment: it's a private method in `ObjectContext`.  Sadly, due to insuficient documentation, you need to look at the source to realize it won't accept base types.